# Mesh modifies after I modify the skeleton in Edit Mode

Tags: modeling, bones

When I select the skeleton of my mesh, enter on *Edit Mode*, move the skeleton, and exit *Edit Mode*, the mesh moves and creates and deform the mesh

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is a video maybe it explains it better

https://streamable.com/p0585e

Here it's a cleaned file with this part of the model, if you wanna take a look :C
[image]

Comment: Probably a constraint that moves the bone towards another once in Pose mode?

Comment: Did you have any idea of how to solve it? :C I'm desperate

Comment: Maybe share the armature so that people can take a look, use https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Here is the file with the problem :C 
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=vVxMDo9k" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/vVxMDo9k/) 

Thankyou for your time, I will add this to the post too :)

Comment: There might be pole target bones for IK constraints that need to be moved down, too. But it's hard to say without more screenshots or better a demo file. If you don't want to share the whole file just share a new blend file with the armature.

Comment: Ohh Tankyou @blunder here its the cuted file :
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=vVxMDo9k" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/vVxMDo9k/)

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to enter in *Pose Mode* (after the modification) press  <kbd>A</kbd> to select all, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply Pose as Reset Pose* and all is working.